# Prolog files recognized as Perl

Tags: programming, mime-type, file-type

Prolog .pl files are shown as Perl files, both in files browser and in Geany/Gedit syntax-highlighting. Is there a way to let it recognized Prolog files as non Perl files?

Answer (score 2):

Perl highlighting can be removed in Geany by choosing `Tools -> Configuration Files -> filetype_extensions.conf` from the menu bar. In the file that is opened, remove `*.pl;` from the Perl line, then choose `Tools -> Reload Configuration` to apply. This will also remove Perl highlighting from actual Perl files with that extension.

Geany doesn't have any highlighting for Prolog, though it is on the [plugin wishlist](http://www.geany.org/Support/PluginWishlist).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this because file types are identified by their file extension, and .pl is the extension for Perl, so changing what they mean would mess with your system.

Comment: I thought they were generally identified by mime type? I never programmed Perl, are you saying that if this association could be changed it would mess up system programs that are written in Perl?

Comment: @NoBugs it would for some file managers and programs. It won't mess with system level things like the bash shell, but you will have problems with Nautilus, for example. The mime type is not used by every program.